# How to make that when you click on the text it was copied pytelegrambotapi

Tags: python, bots, telegram, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I am writing a telegram to the bot.  I ran into such a problem.  I need the bot to send a message (text) when clicked on which it was copied (as a token from @BotFather)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you wish to send a message, that when the user presses it, the text is automatically copied to the user's clipboard, just like the BotFather sends the API token?

[image]

---

This is done by the [MarkDown](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#markdown-style) `parse_mode`;
Send a message with `&parse_mode=MarkDown` and wrap the 'pressable' text in back-ticks (`` ` ``):

```
Hi. `Press me!`!
```

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/sendMessage?chat_id=<id>&text=Hi! `Press me!`&parse_mode=MarkDown
```

[image]

---

**EDIT:**
Bases on [OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59713920/how-to-make-that-when-you-click-on-the-text-it-was-copied-pytelegrambotapi/59714935#comment105607053_59714935) you're looking for a [python-telegram-bot](/questions/tagged/python-telegram-bot) solution.
From there [documentation](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Code-snippets#requesting-location-and-contact-from-user);

```py
bot.send_message(
    chat_id=chat_id, 
    text="*bold* _italic_ `fixed width font` [link](http://google.com).", 
    parse_mode=telegram.ParseMode.MARKDOWN
)
```

Comment: Yes, but I do not quite understand how to realize it in the python. Let's say, there is a code snippet:

bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Hello, my owner')

How to do that the fragment of the text (owner) could be copied?

Comment: Maybe: bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Hello, `my owner`', parse_mode=Markdown) ?

Comment: Maybe: bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Hello, my \`owner\`', parse_mode=Markdown) ?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply by editing the text in following manner
Write   ```   then write your text then again write that 3 character .
Bingo!!!

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked for me for the Telegram Android Client as well as the Telegram Desktop client for windows.

```
bot = telebot.TeleBot(bot_token) #where bot_token is your unique identifier
text = "`" + text + "`" #now make sure the text has the backticks (leading and ending).
```

And then be sure to set the parse mode to markdown (I'm using V2)

```
bot.send_message(bot_chat_id, text, parse_mode='MarkdownV2') #chat_id is another unique identifier
```

I sent a message to myself to demonstrate:

[image: check_all() failed: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'driver']

and with a single click on the message, it gets copied to clipboard!

[image: Text copied to clipboard]

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use HTML because MarkDownV2 requires a lot of escaping:

```
copy_info = f'<code>{chat_info}</code>'
```

Answer (score 0):

await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(chatId, "Здравствуйте `текст для копирования` ", parseMode: ParseMode.Markdown);