# Is it possible in Telegram to copy to clipboard by button?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, telegram-api

I'm writing a telegram bot that will communicate with user and send him url as a result. I want to implement inline button which will do `copy to clipboard` function for user. I want it because copying text by context menu is a bit longer and not that intuitive.

As I understand I can't do this by server-side code (by Python). So I suppose the only solution is to use Telegram functionality (bot's API and Telegram itself). But I can't find any.

I have found only [this answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59714935/7744106). It describes that long press on `Mono` font does copy text. And it does:

[image]

But It seems to me that there's no way to make a link copyable - it always turns to a link.

Can anyone suggest something helpful?

Comment: I guess this is only possible if you send the text as plain text (not as a hyperlink), wrapped in the *'inline fixed-width code'* block, as subscribed in the linked post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you **can't** do this because you don't have any access to user's clipboard maybe because of security reasons.
You can see [how are bots different from humans](https://core.telegram.org/bots#4-how-are-bots-different-from-humans):

So the only possible trick is send as code as [@egvo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7744106/egvo) said in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Using these ``` signs around the message displays a ''copy'' button in Telegram messages like this:
[sample image of the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1NRq.png)