# Text to be sent as a clickable link to telegram from Windows device

Tags: python, hyperlink, telegram

I am trying to send a text message to telegram using python. Text message is basically a Windows command:

```
mstsc.exe /v:10.20.30.40
```

I want this text to act a one-click openable text from telegram. Is this possible?

I tried and it is appearing as a broken link. Example given below.

[image: Issue Screenshot]

Comment: `one-click openable text from telegram` what do you mean by this?

Comment: If you noticed the link doesn't take the whole command as such and on the click takes only the IP address. I want the link to consider the whole command "mstsc.exe /v:10.20.30.40" so with one click, the command can be executed in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible, Telegram Bot API only support a small set of urls, like `t.me` and the normal `http(s)://`, any custom format can't be passed a clickable link.

Source: (Still) Can't find any source in the [Telegram docs](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api), however, I've asked this a few months ago to the [Telegram Bot Support](https://t.me/BotSupport), I wanted to send a clickable `tel:` link, they replied with:

> Hi, at the moment only http/https links will be supported.

---

The closest you can come to mimic this, is by using backticks to make it copy to your clipboard when you press it:

[How to make that when you click on the text it was copied pytelegrambotapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59713920/how-to-make-that-when-you-click-on-the-text-it-was-copied-pytelegrambotapi)