# How to make that when you click on the text it was copied telegram bot api node.js

Tags: node.js, bots, telegram, telegram-bot, node-telegram-bot-api

I am writing a telegram to the bot. I ran into such a problem. I need the bot to send a message (text) when clicked on which it was copied (as a token from @BotFather)
I use node.js

[image: 1]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make that when you click on the text it was copied pytelegrambotapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59713920/how-to-make-that-when-you-click-on-the-text-it-was-copied-pytelegrambotapi)

Comment: Wrap it in backticks and set it to markdown parse mode.

Answer (score 1):

thanks for reaching out.

You can simply do that with `<code>` formatting. The below code can do this:

```js
bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, "<code>Hello World Copiable!</code>", {
    parse_mode: "HTML",
});
```

Regards.